# Lyx not working on Mac Ventura

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts

I recently downloaded Apple Ventura and with my great surprise I'm not longer able to open Lyx. I tried to uninstall and reinstall, to open it despite it's not a Mac app, etc but with no results. How can I solve this issue? The app doesn't open at all...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which TeX distribution to you employ? MacTeX2022? If so, when did you last update it?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I use Miktex console 2.9.7364. From my understanding MacTeX2022 doesn't run on MacOS Ventura.

Comment: @JoshuaMollner MacTeX works just fine on Ventura (heavily tested here, both on Intel and M1 processors). However, I have no experience with LyX.

Comment: @Miyase, thank you! I just downloaded it and now the problem seems to be I cannot update Live Tex Utility to the 2022. Despite that, I still find weird that Lyx doesn't even open. The Tex package should matter for compiling pdf to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: I can confirm @Miyase's claim that MacTeX2022 runs just fine on Ventura on my systems -- a 2022 MacBook M2 Air and a 2021 MacBook M1Max Pro, in case it matters.

Comment: I think the issue is just with Lyx and it’s weird that Lyx app not even opens despite being downloaded. It was working fine before the update

Comment: Unfortunately we've heard from a few people that LyX isn't working well on Ventura. We don't know what the problem is and we only have one LyX developer whose main OS is macOS and I don't even know if he is on Ventura. All that to say, I'm not sure when we will be able to figure out how to work around the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Don't open the application with a double click. Click it while pressing the Control-key instead.

Comment: It doesn't work that way either

Answer (score 0):

Did you allow LyX to run in the security settings of MacOS? You will first need to clear LyX there in order to launch it.

Unfortunately, in Ventura the old Preferences dialog has been replaced by an iOS-style two-column window, but the functionality is the same.

1. Install LyX, then try to launch it by double-clicking.
2. The Finder will complain about LyX coming from an unknown developer.
3. Now you need to change to the Preferences dialog, scroll down to the security settings (left column) and then past all the app settings (right column) to the section where you have the chance to override the settings which block LyX. Confirm with your password.